# Changing the content between a DIV every day

Tags: php, javascript, html

I needed a JS that would change the content of these two div's every day on a yearly basis. For example: on Jan 1 the date div would be "JAN 1" and the moto div would be some moto for Jan 1, then on January 2 the date and the moto changes but not randomly I have text for each of the 365 days. So just a example and I can fill out the rest. I thought JS but can be PHP on serverside if easier.

```
<div id="date"><h3>JAN 1</h3></div>
<div id="moto" align="center">Example Text.</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to humor your request I've provided a solution...like the other answers say, though: this is best done server-side.

```
<script>
    var date = new Date(); //get current date
    var month = date.getMonth();
    var day = date.getDate();
    var months = ['JAN', 'FEB', ... , 'DEC']; //array of month formats

    //define mottos as a multi-dimensional array by month and day
    var mottos = [
        [
            'JAN 1 Motto',
            'JAN 2 Motto',
            ...,
            'JAN 31 Motto'
        ],

        ...,

        [
            'DEC 1 Motto',
            ...,
            'DEC 31 Motto'
        ]
    ];

    //set the Date DIV
    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = months[month] + " " + day;

    //set the Motto DIV; the day - 1 accounts for the zero-indexed arrays
    document.getElementById('moto').innerHTML = mottos[month][day - 1];
</script>
```

With PHP:

```
<?php

    //Similar to the above JS method
    $mottos = array(
        array(
            'Jan 1 Motto',
            ...
        ),
        ...
    );

    $date = new DateTime();
    $month = (int) $date->format('n');
    $day = (int) $date->format('j');
?>

<div id="date"><h3><?php echo strtoupper($date->format('M j')); ?></h3></div>
<div id="moto" align="center"><?php echo $motto[$month - 1][$day - 1];</div>
```

Comment: my question is time zones, would it be a issue with lets say my server is in the states but then the client is in lets say brazil its a 4 hour dif then would it change at midnight on client or server?

Comment: With php it would be based off the server's time.

Answer (score 1):

I would generate the javascript file with some php, totally valid.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a webpage it's not a good idea to put 365 entries in javascript, you'll send all of those to the user, who will only benefit from only one of those. You should generate it with whatever language you have on the backend.

Comment: @Jonny Just use a static JSON file, and load that file via Ajax for instance.

Answer (score 1):

As for the H3, you can make use of [date.js](http://datejs.com).
This code returns today's date in your desired format:

```
Date.today().toString('MMM d')
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/A6u28/

As for the moto, I recommend a JSON file. A JSON file is just a static file (like a regular text file). For instance, you could have this JSON file:

```
{
    "motos": [
        "Moto 1 blah blah blah ... ",
        "Moto 2 blah blah ... ",
        "Moto 3 ... "
    ]
}
```

Then you could use jQuery to retrieve that JSON file and populate your DIV:

```
$.getJSON('http://yourserver.com/motos.json', function(data) {
    $('#moto').text(data.motos[Date.today().getDayOfYear()]);
});
```

So, `Date.today().getDayOfYear()` will return the integer that corresponds to the current day of the year (which is 181 today), so you retrieve the string on the 181-th position of the `'motos'` array from the JSON file...

Comment: yeah I never used JSON so I would'nt know how

Comment: ok thats a way to go but what about years with 366 days? where we have febuary 29?